flutter_background_service package given error on Android API 31
I used flutter_background_service package to run background process. It works other API version without issue but Android API 31 give below error message

Exception has occurred. PlatformException (PlatformException(100,
Failed while read arguments, Caller com.project_name needs to hold
android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM to set exact alarms., null))

I also tried adding below permission to AndroidManifest.xml file but still have this issue.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />

